# Which openCv function can be used to compute BEV perspective transformation given a point coordinates and the camera extrinsics/intrinsics?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, python-3.x, opencv, matrix

I have the `3x3` `intrinsics` and `4x3` `extrinsics` matrices for my camera obtained via `cv2.calibrateCamera()`

Now I want to use these paramenters to compute the `BEV (Bird Eye View)` transformation for any given coordinates in a frame obtained from the camera.

Which `openCv` function can be used to compute the `BEV` perspective transformation for given point coordinates and the camera `extrinsics` and/or `intrinsics` `3x3 matrices`?

I found something very related in the following post: `https://deepnote.com/article/social-distancing-detector/` based on `https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/25/4-point-opencv-getperspective-transform-example/`,

they are using `cv2.getPerspectiveTransform()` to get a `3X3 matrix`, but I don't know whether this matrix represents the `intrinsics`, the `extrinsecs` or something else. Then they are transforming the list of points using such matrix in the following way:

```
#Assuming list_downoids is the list of points to be transformed and matrix is the one obtained above
list_points_to_detect = np.float32(list_downoids).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
transformed_points = cv2.perspectiveTransform(list_points_to_detect, matrix)
```

I really need to know if I can use this `cv2.perspectiveTransform` function to compute the transformation or if there's another better way to do this using the `extrinsics`, the `intrinsics` or both, without having to reuse the frame, since I already have the coordinates of people detected in the frame saved into an array.

Somebody just told me I can reach this if I have at least 3 3D points by using the `cv2.findHomography` function. I'm trying this approach now. Does anyone else have another input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a deep investigation, I found out a good solution:

The `projection matrix` is a multiplication between the`extrinsic` and the `intrinsic` camera matrices

- https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/using-homography-for-pose-estimation-in-opencv-a7215f260fdd
- Since the `extrinsic` is a `4x3` matrix and the `intrinsec` is a `3x3` matrix, but we need the `projection matrix` to be a `3x3` matrix, then we need to convert the `extrinsic` into `3x3` before performing the multiplication.

`cv2.getPerspectiveTransform()` gives us the `Projection Matrix` when we don't have the camera params:

- https://towardsdatascience.com/a-hands-on-application-of-homography-ipm-18d9e47c152f

`cv2.warpPerspective()` transforms the image itsef.

For the problem above we don't need these two functions since we already have the `extrinsics`, the `intrinsecs` and the coordinates of the points in the image.

Considering the presented above, I wrote a function to transform into `BEV` a list o points `list_x_y` given the `intrinsics` and the `extrinsics`:

```
    def compute_point_perspective_transformation(intrinsics, extrinsics, point_x_y):
    """Auxiliary function to project a specific point to BEV
        
        Parameters
        ----------
        intrinsics (array)     : The camera intrinsics matrix
        extrinsics (array)     : The camera extrinsics matrix
        point_x_y (tuple[x,y]) : The coordinates of the point to be projected to BEV
        
        Returns
        ----------
        tuple[x,y] : the projection of the point
    """


        # Using the camera calibration for Bird Eye View
        intrinsics_matrix = np.array(intrinsics, dtype='float32')
        #In the intrinsics we have parameters such as focal length and the principal point

        extrinsics_matrix = np.array(extrinsics, dtype='float32')
        #The extrinsic matrix stores the position of the camera in global space
        #The 1st 3 columns represents the rotation matrix and the last is a translation vector
        extrinsics = extrinsics[:, [0, 1, 3]]
        
        #We removed the 3rd column of the extrinsics because it represents the z coordinate (0)
        projection_matrix = np.matmul(intrinsics_matrix, extrinsics_matrix)
        
        # Compute the new coordinates of our points - cv2.perspectiveTransform expects shape 3
        list_points_to_detect = np.array([[point_x_y]], dtype=np.float32)
        transformed_points = cv2.perspectiveTransform(list_points_to_detect, projection_matrix)
        return transformed_points[0][0][0], transformed_points[0][0][1]
```